# Reloading CORS settings at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-cloud

I recently implemented a `Spring Cloud Config Server`. My application (client) is able to retrieve application profiles and refresh them in flight. 
Unfortunately, CORS settings, which are also declared there, are not reloaded by Spring during runtime. I did a small investigation and check that in terms of refresh everything looks good - `ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder rebind()` method successfully destroys old bean holding CORS setup and creates a new with up-to-date settings. I also see that `Environment` bean is holding new settings in `propertySources` field.

Is there any way to force Spring to reload CORS during runtime or should I need to reload application context?

Comment: I don't know if those settings can be updated in the Framework beans that use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for resolve CORS issue.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but it doesn't answer my question - I don't want to hardcode CORS settings.